# Is there a way to detect if user has enabled the getUserMedia screen-sharing flag in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, webrtc, getusermedia, screensharing

Chrome has the it's upcoming screen sharing functionality behind a flag, which hopefully will be enabled by default. Until then we need to rely on the users to enable this flag, but how do we detect if the flag is enabled or not?

Since the screen sharing capability is exposed as a "chromeMediaSource", we can't do traditional feature detection, to check if an object is present or not.

The only way I can think of is to simply do a try/catch, which seems quite ugly.

So my question: Is there a way to detect if user has enabled the getUserMedia screen-sharing flag in Chrome?

Comment: There's been some discussion on the WebRTC spec lists about handling constraints that aren't supported. https://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/getusermedia/screenshare.html uses the gUM failure callback. (It asks whether you're using HTTPS, but it .)

Answer (score 1):

There will be several scenarios.

1. getUserMedia api not avilable
   You can check if the api is null
2. getUserMedia available. But, user not set the flag. 
   You should get a permission denied error if the user has not enabled screen sharing.

So, you can check for the error and depending on that do your logic.